# How to put local audio to chrome cast in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, google-chrome, http, avaudioplayer

I want to play local audio file to chrome cast device,I am getting MPMedia item and i created server in iPhone using iPhonehttpserver.
My problem is how to send MPMediaitem to chromecast device using httpserver. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the url that points to your (locally) served media to chromecast; your local server on iPhone provides a url through which other clients can access the media, send that url to chromecast so it can play the media.

Comment: Hi Ali Naddaf, Thanks for reply,my server address created by iPhoneserver app is **http://192.168.10.126:8086/** and i got url from MPmedia item is **ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=501031001434352453**, I am facing issue with how to put that MPmedia item url in HTTP server

Comment: I am not familiar with IPhoneserver or so, but once you figure out what is the url for your media, you can pass that to chromecast to play it.